# Retrieving specific tuples using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some problems retrieving specific tuples.
I am actually a student trying to build a Room management system. I have two tables:

```
Room(roomID,hotelname,rate)
```

and

```
Reservation(resID,arriveDate,departDate,roomID).
```

I am not sure how to retrieve the rooms that are available between 2 specific dates.
This was the query that i used.

```
SELECT Room.roomID,hotelname,rate 
  FROM Room 
  LEFT JOIN Reservation 
    on (     Room.roomID=Reservation.resID 
         and arriveDate >='2010-02-16' 
         and departDate <='2010-02-20'
       ) 
 GROUP BY roomID,hotelname,rate 
HAVING count(*)=0;'
```

but it returns an empty set. Can any1 be kind enough to tell me what mistake i am doing??

Comment: Are you sure there are values that match that set?

Comment: yes...Infact there are 6 rooms in the room table and the reservation table has got only entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `Room.roomID=Reservation.resID` should be `Room.roomID=Reservation.roomID`.

You could try a different approach with a subselect:

```
SELECT roomID,hotelname,rate 
FROM Room 
WHERE roomID NOT IN (SELECT roomID FROM Reservation WHERE arriveDate >='2010-02-16' and departDate <='2010-02-20')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...It worked perfectly fine...Now i realize.. i complicaed things unnecessarily :(