# Add column from another table matching results from first MySQL query

Tags: mysql

This is my query for available rooms in choosen period:

```
SELECT rooms.room_id 
  FROM rooms 
 WHERE rooms.room_id NOT IN ( 
   SELECT reservations.room_id 
     FROM reservations 
    WHERE (     reservations.arrivaldate   >=  $arrival_datetime 
            AND reservations.departuredate <=  $departure_datetime
          ) 
       OR (     reservations.arrivaldate   <=  $arrival_datetime 
            AND reservations.departuredate >=  $arrival_datetime 
          ) 
       OR (     reservations.arrivaldate   <=  $departure_datetime 
            AND reservations.departuredate >=  $departure_datetime 
          )
 );
```

How to add average room price column for selected period(from $arrival_datetime to $departure_datetime) from another table (room_prices_table), for every room_id returned from above query. So I need to look in columns whos name is same as room_id...

```
room_prices_table:
date
room0001
room0002
room0003
...
```

Something like

```
SELECT AVG(room0003) 
  FROM room_prices_table 
 WHERE datum IS BETWEEN $arrival_datetime 
                    AND $departure_datetime
```

??

Comment: Is this homework? Looks a lot like a cousin of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269556/retrieving-specific-tuples-using-mysql

Comment: @lexu:  good observation.  Looks like there is a class working on this project :-D

Comment: @Adam Bernier: That was my impression too. His question is different enough to stand on its own, though. But the reservation_range/free_range detection in that other question is better than what he showed (3 ORs!, yuck) us here ..

Comment: Yes. I resisted the urge to replace the ugly WHERE clause.

Comment: It is not homework. Also, no relation with the question you linked, I think my project is very specific. Don't worry about many ORs, I just want to make it work, and optimization is later for desert :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
     r.room_id,
     COALESCE(AVG(rpt.room0003), 0) AS AVERAGE_RATE
FROM rooms r
     LEFT OUTER JOIN room_prices_table rpt
     ON r.room_id = rpt.room_id 
 AND 
     rpt.datum BETWEEN $arrival_datetime AND $departure_datetime
WHERE 
     r.room_id NOT IN (
     SELECT reservations.room_id 
       FROM reservations 
      WHERE (reservations.arrivaldate >=  $arrival_datetime AND 
             reservations.departuredate <=  $departure_datetime) OR 
            (reservations.arrivaldate <=  $arrival_datetime AND
             reservations.departuredate >=  $arrival_datetime) OR
            (reservations.arrivaldate <=  $departure_datetime AND 
             reservations.departuredate >=  $departure_datetime)
     )
GROUP BY
    r.room_id;
```

Using the [COALESCE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) ensures that we get 0 instead of NULL for rooms with no information in the room_prices_table.

Comment: Thank you Adam, I will try to understand this query. But I need it for every room_id returned from reservations, not just for room0003. And what is in r table?

Comment: @Nemi:  have you tried the query?  This should return all `room_id`s, and a `0` for those `room_id`s that do not have `room0003`.  The `r` is just a shorter name for the table rooms called an "alias".  You don't need it, it's just to save typing.

Comment: I made a mistake when giving room0003 in example, the result i want in a row is: 
1. room_id 
2. average_rate_of_room_id_for_given_period

Is it possible with one query?